# Validation to avoid saving same data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a validation for my library system. It should not accept the same accession number. For example, I have two textfields wherein I will input the range 1000-1010 and save it. After that, if i will input another range 1008-1015 it should not be saved even though 1011-15 are not yet existing in the database and it should give an alert that the accession number already existed.

Here is my code for html

```
<table border="1">
   <tr><td><input type="text" name="Acc1" /> - <input type="text" name="Acc2" /> </td></tr>
</table>
```

Assuming there is a button for save.
Here is my code for saving and validation

```
<?php
$Acc1 = $_POST['Acc1'];
$Acc2 = $_POST['Acc2'];

if(isset($_POST['save'])) {

    do{
        $Save = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BOOK WHERE Accession_No = '".$Acc1++."'");
        $Save_Query = mysql_num_rows($Save);

    } while($Acc1 <= $Acc2);
}

if($Save_Query > 0 ) {
    echo "<script language=javascript>
        alert('Accession Number is already taken.');
    </script>";
}

do{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO BOOK('Accession')VALUES('".$Acc1."')");

} while($Acc1 <= $Acc2);

echo "<script language=javascript>
    alert('Successfully Saved.');
    location.href = 'Home.php';
</script>";
?>
```

Thank you for Helping.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: Hammering the table with repeated inserts is a lot less efficient than finding out what the current `MAX(Accesssion_No)` is before taking a first stab.

Comment: It doesn't save even though the database is empty and there is no existing value.

Comment: Please i need help

Comment: Step 1 is to swap out that awful `mysql_query` code with PDO at the very least. Step 2 is to try those queries in the `mysql` command-line tool or through the MySQL Workbench tool to see if they work. You're not testing for errors at all, so who knows what's wrong here.

Comment: @tadman Your first comment makes a bold assertion. Are you sure?

Comment: @ManuSharma See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - and I only have a limited supply of kittens, so please stop using this API.